# How can I deploy a Next.js web-app from my Github repository using Vercel.com?

Tags: typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

On my Next js project I was able to deploy from my Github Nextjs repository. I disabled the ESLint, and now I need to do something else with the URL endpoints for my pages, but I don't know what to do.

```
Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Cloning github.com/gmiDAO/gmi-frontend (Branch: minor-changes, Commit: 0e10bf8)
Cloning completed: 523.049ms
Previous build caches not available
Running "vercel build"
Vercel CLI 31.4.0
Running "install" command: `yarn install`...
yarn install v1.22.17
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @monaco-protocol/client@2.0.0" has incorrect peer dependency "@project-serum/anchor@~0.25.0".
warning " > @monaco-protocol/client@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "bs58@^4.0.1".
warning "@solana/wallet-adapter-react > @solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile > @react-native-async-storage/async-storage@1.17.11" has unmet peer dependency "react-native@^0.0.0-0 || 0.60 - 0.71 || 1000.0.0".
warning "@solana/wallet-adapter-react > @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-react > @solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base@1.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "bs58@^4.0.1".
warning "@solana/wallet-adapter-react > @solana-mobile/wallet-adapter-mobile > @solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol-web3js > @solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter-protocol@0.9.9" has unmet peer dependency "react-native@>0.69".
warning "notistack > goober@2.1.12" has unmet peer dependency "csstype@^3.0.10".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
Done in 31.55s.
Detected Next.js version: 13.1.6
Running "npm run build"
> faaqt-frontend@0.1.0 build
> next build
warn  - You have enabled experimental features (appDir, fontLoaders) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.
info  - Thank you for testing `appDir` please leave your feedback at https://nextjs.link/app-feedback
Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
https://nextjs.org/telemetry
info  - Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
 daisyUI components 2.50.0  https://daisyui.com
  ✔︎ Including:  base, components, 1 themes, utilities
  ❤︎ Support daisyUI:  https://opencollective.com/daisyui 
  
info  - Compiled successfully
info  - Skipping linting
info  - Checking validity of types...
info  - Collecting page data...
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
warn  - Statically exporting a Next.js application via `next export` disables API routes and middleware.
This command is meant for static-only hosts, and is not necessary to make your application static.
Pages in your application without server-side data dependencies will be automatically statically exported by `next build`, including pages powered by `getStaticProps`.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/api-routes-static-export
info  - Generating static pages (0/8)
info  - Generating static pages (2/8)
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
```

Until this point everything went good.

From this point I am facing the following errors during the deployment. As follows the trace that I've obtained from trying to deploy on Vercel.com:

```
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
Error occurred prerendering page "/faaqt/[id]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
Error occurred prerendering page "/register". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
info  - Generating static pages (4/8)
Error occurred prerendering page "/login". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
info  - Generating static pages (6/8)
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
Error occurred prerendering page "/profile/[[...userId]]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
Error occurred prerendering page "/events/[[...userId]]". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
TypeError: Endpoint URL must start with `http:` or `https:`.
    at assertEndpointUrl (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:17804:11)
    at new Connection (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/882.js:19000:25)
    at ProgramProvider (/vercel/path0/.next/server/chunks/38.js:231:24)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:99:272)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
    at be (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:107:98)
    at de (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:106:424)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:222)
    at ae (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:103:386)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:105:91)
> Build error occurred
Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /(protected)/events/[[...userId]]/page: /events/[[...userId]]
    /(protected)/faaqt/[id]/page: /faaqt/[id]
    /(protected)/page: /
    /(protected)/profile/[[...userId]]/page: /profile/[[...userId]]
    /login/page: /login
    /register/page: /register
    at /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:415:19
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1400:21
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:1259:17
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:79:20)
    at async Object.build [as default] (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:66:29)
info  - Generating static pages (8/8)
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

There is no way to configure http and https on a next js project. I was expecting that Vercel.com will manage that for me. Maybe it is related to the API call that my app does to the backend.

As follows an example of API call on my project (fetch belongs to Next js framework)

```
import { LoginData, RegisterData } from '../types/auth';

export const login = async (data: LoginData) => {
  const { email, password } = data;
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FAAQT_API_URL}auth/login`,
    {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ email, password })
    }
  );
  return response.json();
};
```

An the value of the constant

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_FAAQT_API_URL=https://backend.faaqt.com/v1/
```

Comment: The error Vercel reports is not related to where Vercel is deploying.

Are you making any api calls in your Next.js app? If yes, can you share code for those?

It's possible that the url used there might be missing the `http:` or `https:`.

Comment: Does this mean that the actually problems is on my backend api calls? Yes, the app does api call.

Comment: Yes. I suspect that in one of your api calls within your app, the url constructed is missing the `http:` or `https:`